# nuxtjs set response header for 200 status code only

Tags: error-handling, http-headers, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

In `nuxtjs`, in SSR mode, where/how can I set custom response headers for an endpoint
only for 200 OK response code?

There are cases where something goes wrong like 404 not found pages, or 500 internal server error pages, for those I do not want in any circumstances to set the custom header. I need to set `X-Accel-Expires` response header for 200 response code to tell nginx to cache it and for how long, I dont want errors to be cached.

Currently I'm solving it with the following custom module where I explicitly overwrite previously set `X-Accel-Expires` with `0` (aka. to disable caching) :

```js
//modules/get-rid-off-custom-header-module/index.js

module.exports = function nuxtCustomHeaders(options) {
    const nuxt = this.nuxt;

    const renderer = nuxt.renderer;
    const renderRoute = renderer.renderRoute.bind(renderer);

    renderer.renderRoute = async function(route, context) {
        try {
            const result = await renderRoute(route, context);

            if (context.nuxt.error) {//eg. we got 404 page
                context.res.setHeader('X-Accel-Expires', '0');
            }

            return result;
        } catch(e) {//rendering failed, 500 internal server error
            context.res.setHeader('X-Accel-Expires', '0');
            throw e;
        }
    };
};
```

But the above solution just seems to be wrong. I'm hacking nuxt.
How this functionality can be achieved cleanly?

Comment: have you tried [server middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/) ?

Comment: yes, it is called before rendering process even starts, is unusable

Comment: yes but i think you could modify response headers too

Comment: I can modify response headers there too, but at that point page is not rendered yet, so If I set response header there it will be part of 4xx, 5xx request responses when rendering fails.. Thats the issue I'm trying to solve here.. It would be handy if there was a hook triggered just after response code is set by nuxt but before response headers are sent for every route so I can modify or set response properties based on whats happening..